# Using Akka.NET Cluster Sharding can the shard id change over time?

Tags: akka, sharding, event-sourcing, akka.net

I'm considering using [Cluster Sharding with Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-sharding) and initially I chose a value within my aggregate as the shard id that may change for my aggregate over time. Essentially it is a property that represents the association with another aggregate (like a foreign key in relational). Is this going to present me with problems with sharding? I'm imagining difficulties within the sharding implementation in locating the entities within the shards if the id being used to shard is changed.